# Awk print with pipes not working iPython in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: awk, pipe, ipython, jupyter-notebook

So the command below does not give me any output in Jupyter Notebook with iPython:

```
IP = '62.172.72.131'
!cat hits.csv | grep {IP} | awk '{print $1}'
```

I have tried both double and single "$" sign and none of them works. If I only use one pipe in the command, it works fine. For example:

```
IP = '62.172.72.131'
!cat hits.csv | grep {IP}
!cat hits.csv | awk '{print $1}'
```

Anyone know why this is happening?
Thanks!

Comment: You may want to provide a few relevant lines from your input file.

Answer (score 6):

I think I figured this out. The "$" and "{" and "}" are all special characters in iPython, so I have to escape them by doubling them.

```
IP = '62.172.72.131'
!cat hits.csv | grep {IP} | awk '{{print $$1}}'
```