# Awk kills Jupyter

Tags: awk, jupyter

I'm trying to run a simple awk command in my notebook and I have to restart the kernel every time -- never completes.

```
report = "./November2018/November2018_munged.csv"
!head $report
!awk -F'\t' '{print $4}' $report
```

The `head` command completes but not the `awk` command.

Comment: Perhaps your file is too big.  try `!head "$report" | awk -F'\t' '{print $4}'`  to check whether it runs.  It's good habit to double quote variable names as well.

Comment: It's only about 60 lines.

Comment: Or replace `awk` script with `cut -f4`

Comment: Actually, I should really invest more time into pandas and numpy. Trying to remember quoting and escape idiosyncrasies between 2 shell platforms is a pain!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34972035/awk-print-with-pipes-not-working-ipython-in-jupyter-notebook), try scaping the `$ { }` characters by duplicating them.

```
!awk -F'\t' '{{print $$4}}' $report
```

Comment: With one minor tweak, this worked. Single dollar sign on report var. Thanks!